# How can I insert record into SQLServer 2008 database?

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I'm having trouble inserting data from my registration webform into sqlserver-2008. I'm getting an error in VS: The connection was not closed. The connection's current state is open.

Here's the code that I have:

```
protected void buttonRegister(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection objCon = new SqlConnection(strCon);

    try
    {
        objCon.ConnectionString = strCon;
        objCon.Open();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        this.lblConnect.Text = "Unable to connect to database.";
    }

    if (objCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        Session["users"] = this.txtUsername.Text;
        Session["pwd"] = this.txtPassword.Text;
        lblConnect.Text = "Connected";

        string sql = @"INSERT INTO user (firstname, middlename, lastname, username, email, password) VALUES ('" + txtFirstname.Text
            + "' , '" + txtMiddlename.Text + "', '" + txtLastname.Text + "', '" + txtUsername.Text + "', '" + txtEmailAddr.Text
            + "', '" + txtPassword.Text + "')";

        objCon.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, objCon);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        objCon.Close();
        objCon.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        lblConnect.Text = "Unable to connect to database.";
                    objCon.Close();
        objCon.Dispose();

    }
    objCon.Close();
    objCon.Dispose();

}
```

Any idea why it is not inserting into the SQL Server? Please help! Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Hi! If you want to include source code in your post you should indent it by four spaces, so it will be properly formatted. Or you can just select all your code and click on the button with the curly braces :)

Comment: Considering using a table adapter. Your code is subject to SQL Injection as is. Very dangerous!

Comment: @flaviotsf this looks like copypasta to me. I think he's just trying to learn how the DB connection works. You're absolutely right re: SQL Injection but he's probably best served be keeping it simple for now, IMHO.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks to me like you're opening `objCon` a second time. Your `if` makes sure it's open, then you try to open it again after you assign the sql string.

You have this condition:

```
if (objCon.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
```

then, within that condition you say `objCon.Open();`

Eliminate that problematic `objCon.Open();`

Comment: thanks. i got rid of that duplicate and the insert seems to be working. i have a primary key id in my table and my sql statement is string sql = @"INSERT INTO flightuser (id, firstname, middlename, lastname, username, email, password) VALUES ('" + '2' + "', '" + txtFirstname.Text
                + "' , '" + txtMiddlename.Text + "', '" + txtLastname.Text + "', '" + txtUsername.Text + "', '" + txtEmailAddr.Text
                + "', '" + txtPassword.Text + "')"; How do I make it so I don't have to specify the id?

Comment: I'm not sure what your comment is asking. If your PK is an autonumber when you probably shouldn't explicitly set a value for it.

Comment: How do i set id to autoincrement every time a new record is inserted?